# DTexec /ISSERVER path for package

Tags: ssis, dtexec

When I try to execute a SSIS package created in sql server data tools (vs 2010) using dtexec, I receive an error "is not a valid server package path". The documentation says use: dtexec /ISServer [path to package]. If I connect via SSMS I can browse the Integration Services Catalog, and the path is:
"SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\Projects\KTAKTranslatorPro\Packages\KTAKTrans.dtsx"
However,

- dtexec /ISSERVER \SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\Projects\KTAKTranslatorPro\Packages\KTAKTrans.dtsx

produces the above error. I've also tried:

- dtexec /ISSERVER SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\Projects\KTAKTranslatorPro\Packages\KTAKTrans.dtsx
- dtexec /ISSERVER \SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\Projects\KTAKTranslatorPro\Packages\KTAKTrans.dtsx
- dtexec /ISSERVER \SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\KTAKTranslatorPro\KTAKTrans.dtsx
- dtexec /ISSERVER SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\KTAKTranslatorPro\KTAKTrans.dtsx

Still same error.

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to execute the package from the integration services catalog, and viewed the execution report; the package was listed (under the Name component) as "KTAKTranslator\KTAKTranslatorPro\KTAKTrans.dtsx" with none of the "folders" that appear while browsing the catalog in SSMS. I added a SINGLE "\" before that string and the package ran.

dtexec /ISSERVER \SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\KTAKTranslatorPro\KTAKTrans.dtsx

Oh paths; help me help you.

Comment: Isn't that the same option you listed above (second to last) and listed as error?

Comment: In my SSMS object explorer, the full tree path looks like this:
{Server Node}\Integration Services Catalogs\SSISDB\Ipas\Projects\IntegrationServices\Packages\OracleSync.dtsx
In order for me to run the package, I had to execute the command like this:  
dtexec /ISSERVER \SSISDB\Ipas\IntegrationServices\OracleSync.dtsx
Note that the path is specified starting with \SSISDB\ and excludes the \Projects\ and \Packages\ parts....

Answer (score 0):

not an expert but can you try this one:
DTExec /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\Projects\KTAKTranslatorPro\Packages\KTAKTrans.dtsx" /SERVER "."
Regards M

Answer (score 0):

This was the command that I used.  I also am making use of an environment variable (`/ENVREFERENCE 3` - pointing to my "test" environment) as well as a couple of optional parameters.

```
dtexec /ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\KTAKTranslator\KTAKTranslatorPro\KTAKTrans.dtsx\"" /SERVER servername /ENVREFERENCE 3 /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /REPORTING E
```

Hope this helps